# Yahoo Finance data query counting and efficiency

Tags: php, objective-c, c, ios5, yahoo-finance

I am developing a web application which will use financial data from yahoo finance. As I know there is a limit of queries (500k). So, I am implementing an auto fill search field which will send request for every press of the key starting from first symbol. As I understand this kind of tool will generate a lot of queries without significant job done.

Is there any solution, which can efficiently allocation queries? Database?

What is the best practice using such financial data sources?

Right now I am programming with PHP, also I am developing similar application in iOS, so what are the best solutions you can suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: pay for a better data feed? just like yahoo does

Answer (score 0):

My 3D stock charting application stores (caches, to be precise) the data in flat files in a tmp sub-folder with file names similar to the symbol successfully retrieved. The application checks the date on the file and if it's not recent enough, well, it fetches new data. I could have used a database, but after going through 3 server moves and several databases I haven't had to update it. It just works.